# python smtplib failing to run (SMTP AUTH extension not supported)

Tags: python, smtp

I would like to send email and you can see my python source code:

```
import smtplib

email = "smtpsender1001@gmail.com"
password = "ksarvsqstghnvbou"
connection = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.mail.yahoo.com")
connection.login(user=email, password=password)
connection.sendmail(from_addr=email, to_addrs="smtpsender1001@gmail.com")
connection.close()
```

When I run, this code raises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mini\Desktop\Python\100DaysofCode\Day32\newmain.py", line 7, in <module>
    connection.login(user=email, password=password)
  File "C:\Users\Mini\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\smtplib.py", line 716, in login
    raise SMTPNotSupportedError(
smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
```

Can someone suggest a solution for this issue?

Comment: Why do you try to log in to yahoo with a gmail address? What happens when you don't use the `connection.login`?

Answer (score 0):

smtp.mail.yahoo.com does not support AUTH over unecrypted connection.

Use [`smtplib.SMTP_SSL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP_SSL) instead of [`smtplib.SMTP`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP) to start encrypted connection to port smtps (465) supported by smtp.mail.yahoo.com.
**OR**
Execute [`connection.starttls()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.starttls) before executing `connection.login()`. smtp.mail.yahoo.com supports STARTRLS ESMTP extension and offers AUTH after it is issued.